# delete command in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am working vb.net in visual stdio 2005.
I want to delete a row from my table the tables's name is displayed in listbox, 
when I press delete button in my app nothing happen's.

```
 Private Sub cmdDELETE_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDELETE.Click
        Me.SqlConnection1.Open()
        Dim mycom As SqlCommand
        Dim ra As Integer
        mycom = New SqlCommand("DELETE @PICTUREDATA From pic WHERE 
        (NAME = '+ ListBox1.SelectedItem + ')", Me.SqlConnection1)
        ra = mycom.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("ROWS AFFECTED " & ra)
        Me.SqlConnection1.Close()
    End Sub
```

any help plzz

Comment: Can you try executing the query DELETE @PICTUREDATA From pic WHERE (NAME = '+ ListBox1.SelectedItem + ') " - with the Selected item value as passed to the code - directly in the DB and check if that achieves the desired result? The code SEEMS pretty OK..u will need to debug it to really pinpoint where the problem lies..

Answer (score 2):

If you have copy-pasted the code, there is at least one error with quoting.
It should be like this:

```
mycom = New SqlCommand("DELETE @PICTUREDATA From pic WHERE 
(NAME = '" + ListBox1.SelectedItem + "')", Me.SqlConnection1
```

But you should really consider using the [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) collection to add your input data. Your code is open to SQL injection attacks.